# This wouldn't be on topic on Language Learning, would it?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Not sure if pedagogy is on-topic here. Let me know if it happens to be, and I shall effect the migration.

[Constructivism Learning Theory for English language Teaching [closed]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/269847/constructivism-learning-theory-for-english-language-teaching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about learning theories and what they mean for teachers are on topic on Language Learning Stack Exchange. That specific question would be accepted here if it were migrated. (Apparently, we don't have any questions about constructivism yet.)